# ASP.Net localization InitializeCulture controls always null

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms

I must be missing something super basic...  but trying to do localization using resource files and I'm simply using the MSDN example found [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

On the code behind of my page:

```
  Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        If Request.Form("listLanguages") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim selectedLanguage As String = _
                Request.Form("listLanguages")
            UICulture = Request.Form("listLanguages")
            Culture = Request.Form("listLanguages")
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New  _
                CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)
        End If
        MyBase.InitializeCulture()
    End Sub
```

In my markup:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnStart"  autocomplete="off" >
                   <asp:Label ID="lblLanguageChoice" AssociatedcontrolID="listLanguages" runat="server" Text="Language Options"></asp:Label>
                   <asp:ListBox ID="listLanguages" runat="server">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="en"  Selected="True" Text="English"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="es" Text="Español"></asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:ListBox>
                   <asp:Button ID="btnChangeLanguage" runat="server" 
                    Text="Change Language" />
.......
```

but when stepping through the code (after selecting the language and hitting the button)  the list box is always "nothing" - which sort of makes sense given how early in the page cycle this event is fired.

How can I get this routine to know my language choice?  I tried stuffing the choice made into a session variable on the button click, but then I am a "click behind".  (Click once, it saves the language choice but stays in default language.  Click twice, and it switches to the selected language.)  I need a solution that refreshes at the moment of the button click and doesn't require the user to hit it twice.

**EDIT:**
I found the reason - now I just have to figure out how to fix it!  It's that crazy ASP naming convention thing.  My list box is NOT named "listLanguages".  Stepping through it turns out to be named "ctl00$MainContent$listLanguages".  ClientIDMode static does not resolve it because that changes the id but not the name.  Will post once I solve completely.

**EDIT2:**
Here we go.  It's a bit hackish and only works because there aren't a lot of parameters on this page.  If anyone knows a more elegant solution, I would really appreciate it!

```
  Dim request As HttpRequest = Me.Request
        Dim params As NameValueCollection = request.Form
        For Each par As String In params.AllKeys
            If par.Contains("listLanguages") Then
                Dim selectedLanguage As String = request(par)
                UICulture = request(par)
                Culture = request(par)
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)
            End If
        Next

        MyBase.InitializeCulture()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure if this will be helpful for you as the answer is very late.

The solution is the following:

1. Get the UniqueID of the control
2. Use PageMethods (or jquery ajax) call to pass the unique id to server side
3. Store the id in a static variable
4. Use this static variable in your "InitializeCulture" method

The following is the code for each step. I have used DropDownList instead of ListBox but that should not matter. Also the code is in C# but converting the same into VB.NET should not be a challenge.

For step 1 and 2:

Enable page method as

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Call a method on the code behind using "PageMethods" as

```
$("document").ready(function () { PageMethods.SendForm('<%= DropDownList1.UniqueID %>', OnSucceeded, OnFailed); });
```

For Step 3:

```
    static string dropDownUniqueID;

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SendForm(string uniqueID)
    {
        dropDownUniqueID = uniqueID;
    }
```

For Step 4:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Request.Form[dropDownUniqueID] != null)
        {
            UICulture = Request.Form[dropDownUniqueID];
            Culture = Request.Form[dropDownUniqueID];
        }

        //This is not working
        //if (Request.Form["DropDownList1"] != null)
        //{
        //    UICulture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
        //    Culture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
        //}

        //This is your solution
        //foreach (string item in Request.Form)
        //{
        //    if (item.Contains("DropDownList1"))
        //    {
        //        UICulture = Request.Form[item];
        //        Culture = Request.Form[item];
        //    }
        //}

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Regards,

Samar

Comment: that is a very nice solution.  But it depends on javascript, which means someone using the site MUST have javascript enabled.  Still, seems like it would work well.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not actually using it. I'm still using my solution because it is not javascript dependent. So I didn't check it as an answer.  But I'll give you the rep and check it.